# First Post review test question broken

Tags: bug, review-audits, review-queue

The following test question (i.e., review audit) for the First Post review queue seems to be broken:
https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/312931#

Neither comments nor flags work and the buttons for them do not respond.

The original question:

```
System hanging after my log in

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS on my PC using CD. But after the successful
installation and after my log in on PC it is hanging.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an audit.

It's actually based on a question that was deleted a while ago so no, you can't *do* anything to it. Just mark it for closure (because it was a bad question with no detail and no updates) and you'd have passed.

Comment: Well, I know that... But the flag button did not respond, neitehr did the comment button.